# Serialize jackson setting the default type for a pojo

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, json-serialization

I've a pojo as below:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = @class)
public class Shape {

public final String abc;
public final String xyz;

}
```

Rest api accepts object of Shape as a parameter, wherein I've to pass object like this:

`{ @class = com.test.Shape, abc = "test1", xyz = "test2"}`.

I want json to be passed like

```
{ abc = "test1", xyz = "test2"}
```

Basically, I want to deserialise pojo without passing @class key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this using by adding sprint property in config file:

```
spring.jackson.mapper.USE_BASE_TYPE_AS_DEFAULT_IMPL: true
```

Below is the reference for the same:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.spring-mvc.customize-jackson-objectmapper

Answer (score 0):

In your Rest API,You can put @RequestBody @Validated before the Shape parameter.
like

```
    @PostMapping("/test")
    public void api(@RequestBody @Validated Shape shape){
    todo
    }
```

It should be noted that @RequestBody needs to take effect under the post request

Comment: This didn't work. anything else, you can suggest me to look for?

Comment: I'm sorry for not giving a perfect example, you can read it again now. The following is the description of the official website, you can also read it very smoothly.https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body

Comment: I'm not sure if my question is clear, edited it a bit. I don't want UI to pass "@class=classname". This solution doesn't seem to work and url you shared is doesn't has any detail related to the problem.

Comment: I understand exactly what you want, and I tested it a bit, the example is indeed no problem. The @RequestBody annotation maps the HttpRequest body to a transfer or domain object, enabling automatic deserialization of the inbound HttpRequest body onto a Java object.
So you don’t need to specify the corresponding calss like "@class=classname"